# How to change the behaviour or display of the language switcher?

Tags: 7, theming, i18n-l10n

On translated pages the language switcher shows links to translated languages, but for untranslated languages there is no link, but the name of the language without a link. In the case, that there is no corresponding node in a given language, i would like the language switcher to show a link to the front page instead.

How can i accomplish this behaviour? Thank you very much!

Comment: You can do it just using page, or node templates and CSS rules.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add next into template.php file of your theme:

```
<?php 
  function YOURTHEMENAME_links__locale_block($variables) {
    foreach($variables['links'] as $key => $lang) {
      if (isset($lang['attributes']['class']) && in_array('locale-untranslated', $lang['attributes']['class'])) {
        // Set here any page link.
        $variables['links'][$key]['href'] = '<front>';
      }
    }
    return theme_links($variables);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Are these <front> links localized then?

Comment: This front/home page will point to current selected language front page.

Comment: Thank you again, i think your solution is a lot better than the one i ended up using :)

Answer (score 4):

there is a module for this now - Language Switcher Fallback. Does exactly what you asked, directing the user to the frontpage if no translation to a node. See here https://drupal.org/project/language_switcher_fallback

Answer (score 1):

In the end I used this approach.

```
function YOURTHEME_language_switch_links_alter(array &$links, $type, $path) {
  $language_type = variable_get('translation_language_type', LANGUAGE_TYPE_INTERFACE);

  if ($type == $language_type && preg_match("!^node/(\d+)(/.+|)!", $path, $matches)) {
    $node = node_load((int) $matches[1]);

    if (empty($node->tnid)) {
      // If the node cannot be found nothing needs to be done. If it does not
      // have translations it might be a language neutral node, in which case we
      // must leave the language switch links unaltered. This is true also for
      // nodes not having translation support enabled.
      if (empty($node) || entity_language('node', $node) == LANGUAGE_NONE || !translation_supported_type($node->type)) {
        return;
      }
      $langcode = entity_language('node', $node);
      $translations = array($langcode => $node);
    }
    else {
      $translations = translation_node_get_translations($node->tnid);
    }

    foreach ($links as $langcode => $link) {
      if (isset($translations[$langcode]) && $translations[$langcode]->status) {
        // Translation in a different node.
        $links[$langcode]['href'] = 'node/' . $translations[$langcode]->nid . $matches[2];
      }
      else {
        // No translation in this language, or no permission to view.
        $links[$langcode]['href'] = '<front>';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Which replaces this code fragment in the original Translation module.

```
  else {
    // No translation in this language, or no permission to view.
    unset($links[$langcode]['href']);
    $links[$langcode]['attributes']['class'][] = 'locale-untranslated';
```

I am pretty sure the other solution is more beautiful, but this solution is also working.

Comment: First solution did not work for me... This one worked as charm! Thx.