# How to only display languages in language switcher block where a translation exists?

Tags: 7, theming, i18n-l10n

I need to enable thousands of languages on my Drupal 7 site, but I do not want to incur the rendering overhead of creating the language switcher sidebar for every language. The default behavior for the language switcher block is to show languages which do not have translations in gray font and struck out.

How would I modify the language switcher block to only show active links, i.e. only display the languages for which a translation exists? I looked at this code from [this post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/58882/how-to-change-the-behaviour-or-display-of-the-language-switcher) but need help adjusting it for my needs:

```
<?php 
  function YOURTHEMENAME_links__locale_block($variables) {
  foreach($variables[links] as $key => $lang) {
    if (isset($lang['attributes']['class']) && in_array('locale-untranslated', $lang['attributes']['class'])) {
      $variables['links'][$key]['href'] = '<front>'; // Set here any page link...
    }
  }
  return theme_links($variables);
}
```

What should the code be, and where do I put the code in my theme?

Comment: Update: I tried the suggestion in this comment (http://groups.drupal.org/node/139329#comment-599034) but it does not work. The links still appear as before.

Comment: After trying [this](https://groups.drupal.org/node/139329#comment-599034), I don't think you need to do anything else. What is happening? What is not working? I have tried same code and everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

To adapt the [solution you tried](https://groups.drupal.org/node/139329#comment-599034), you would just have to unset entries for languages where no translation exists, so no link will be printed for them in the `theme_links()` call. So:

```
function YOURTHEMENAME_links__locale_block($variables) {

  foreach($variables['links'] as $key => $lang) {
    if (isset($lang['attributes']['class'])) {
        if (in_array('locale-untranslated', $lang['attributes']['class'])) {
            unset($variables['links'][$key]);
        }
    }
  }
  return theme_links($variables);
}
```

You would put this code into the `template.php` file of your theme, adapting the `YOURTHEMENAME` part of the function name above according to how all the other functions in your theme start. Means, you always start the function name of all your theme functions with the so-called "machine name" of your theme.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. This is exactly what I was looking for. However when I show all Drupal log messages, it says Notice: Use of undefined constant links - assumed 'links' in basetheme_links__locale_block() (line 1252 of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/d7-site/sites/all/themes/basetheme/template.php).
Notice: Use of undefined constant links - assumed 'links' in basetheme_links__locale_block() (line 1255 of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/d7-site/sites/all/themes/basetheme/template.php).

Comment: Note: You've forgotten quotes around $variables['links']

Answer (score 0):

There is also a different way to determine missing translations. Namely, instead of looking for a `locale-untranslated` CSS class for the link, you can check if the link is the same as the one for the *current* language. Because that is the Drupal Core default behaviour for the language switcher in case a translation is missing. So:

```
function YOURTHEMENAME_links__locale_block($variables) {
    global $language;

    if (isset($data[$language->language])) {
        $current_href = $variables[links][$language->language]['href'];
    }
    else {
        $current_href = false;
    }

    foreach ($variables[links] as $key => $lang) {
        // If we find a missing translation, remove its entry from the list.
        if ($lang['href'] == $current_href) {
            unset($variables[links][$key]);
        }
    }

    return theme_links($variables);
}
```

Again, this function would go into your theme's `template.php`.

Answer (score 0):

This would more likely work:

```
   $current_href = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->getId();

    foreach (array_keys($variables["links"]) as $key) {
    // If we find a missing translation, remove its entry from the list.
    if ($key == $current_href) {
      unset($variables["links"][$key]);
    }
  }
```